# Numerical solution in Matlab or any other solver

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematica, matlab

I need to find x of this equation:

1.0221044505936159^x +
 1.0446975079232772^x +
 1.0677899723724409^x +
 1.091392883061106^x +
 1.1155175231229544^x +
 1.140175425099138^x +
 1.1653783764512973^x +
 1.1911384251964328^x +
 1.2174678856663448^x +
 1.24437934439437^x +
 1.2718856661322526^x +
 1.3287357857717006^x +
 1.3581067603002603^x +
 1.3881269640841731^x +
 1.4188107479794378^x +
 1.3^x == 21

Most probably, it's not possible to solve it analytically but numerically...

I tried Mathematica, but the respond was like:

The equations appear to involve the variables to be solved for in an essentially non-algebraic way.

Any idea if there is a numerical solver online that could solve it?
How about Matlab?

Comment: You need http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the information provided by @user1111261 in the comments, the question can more precisely be described as finding a solution to:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{16} (1.3^{i/12})^x = 21$$

Using some algebra, the summation can equivalently be written as

$$\sum_{i=1}^{16} (1.3^{i/12})^x = \sum_{i=1}^{16} 1.3^{ix/12} = \sum_{i=1}^{16} (1.3^{x/12})^i = \sum_{i=1}^{16} r^i, \quad (r = 1.3^{x/12})$$

This is a simple [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), so we can eliminate the summation and write it neatly as

$$\sum_{i=1}^{16} r^i = \frac{r^{17} - r}{r - 1}, \quad (r = 1.3^{x/12})$$

Since this has to equal $21$, we get

$$\frac{r^{17} - r}{r - 1} = 21 \ \Leftrightarrow \ r^{17} - r = 21r - 21 \ \Leftrightarrow \ r^{17} - 22r + 21 = 0, \quad (r = 1.3^{x/12})$$

This equation has three real roots: one at $r_1 = 1$, one negative root at $r_0 \approx -1.25$ and one positive root at $r_2 \approx 1.03$. I do not think you can find a nicer expression for this root $r_2$, but we need that root. We then get

$$1.3^{x/12} = r_2 \ \Leftrightarrow \ \frac{x}{12} \log 1.3 = \log r_2 \ \Leftrightarrow \ x = \frac{12 \log r_2}{\log 1.3}$$

So with one line in *Mathematica*,

```
In[1] := (12 Log[r] / Log[1.3]) /. FindRoot[r^17 - 22 r + 21 == 0, {r, 1.03}]
```

We get the result

```
Out[1] = 1.4091023318304141
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should obtain solution using Mathematica NSolve command :

```
NSolve[1.0221044505936159^x + 1.0446975079232772^x + 
1.0677899723724409^x + 1.091392883061106^x + 
1.1155175231229544^x + 1.140175425099138^x + 
1.1653783764512973^x + 1.1911384251964328^x + 
1.2174678856663448^x + 1.24437934439437^x + 1.2718856661322526^x + 
1.3287357857717006^x + 1.3581067603002603^x + 
1.3881269640841731^x + 1.4188107479794378^x + 1.3^x == 
21, x, Reals]
```

$x=1.4091$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple implementation of the [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) in *Mathematica*, which uses the fact that the expression is (strictly) increasing in $x$. First we insert the function as $f$:

```
f[x_] := 1.0221044505936159^x + 1.0446975079232772^x + 
  1.0677899723724409^x + 1.091392883061106^x + 
  1.1155175231229544^x + 1.140175425099138^x + 
  1.1653783764512973^x + 1.1911384251964328^x + 
  1.2174678856663448^x + 1.24437934439437^x + 
  1.2718856661322526^x + 1.3287357857717006^x + 
  1.3581067603002603^x + 1.3881269640841731^x + 
  1.4188107479794378^x + 1.3^x;
```

Then set up two lists `A = {0};` and `B = {3};` with initial values $a_0 = 0$ and $b_0 = 3$, such that $16 = f(a_0) < 21 < f(b_0) = 29.236\ldots$. Now implement a loop that decreases the search space by a factor $2$ every time, for some number of iterations (in this case $30$), by checking if the solution is in the right half or in the left half of the interval formed by the last elements of `A` and `B`:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 30, i++, 
  m = (Last[A] + Last[B])/2; 
  If[f[m] < 21, AppendTo[A, m], AppendTo[B, m]];
];
```

Finally, we output the left side and the right side of the small interval where the solution can be found: `{N[Last[A],10], N[Last[B],10]}`. The output from *Mathematica* is $\{1.409102323, 1.409102325\}$. So the solution $x$ is given by $x = 1.40910232\ldots$

Comment: Btw, there is no way to solve it analytically?

I've been thinking about it for 6 months now...

Comment: @user1111261: I don't think you will be able to solve it analytically. Unless you have some specific useful information about those numbers $1.022\ldots$ etc.

Comment: They are these numbers: (1.3)^16/12 , (1.3)^15/12, .... (1.3)^1/12. Altogether it's 16 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach in Mathematica using `FindRoot`:

```
In[1]:= FindRoot[
 1.0221044505936159^x + 1.0446975079232772^x + 1.0677899723724409^x + 
   1.091392883061106^x + 1.1155175231229544^x + 1.140175425099138^x + 
   1.1653783764512973^x + 1.1911384251964328^x + 
   1.2174678856663448^x + 1.24437934439437^x + 1.2718856661322526^x + 
   1.3287357857717006^x + 1.3581067603002603^x + 
   1.3881269640841731^x + 1.4188107479794378^x + 1.3^x == 21, {x, 1}]

Out[1]= {x -> 1.4091}
```

Since `FindRoot` is an implementation of Newton's method, you must provide a first approximation to the root. In this case I have chosen $1$.

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I do not know how to do it even for a simpler equation like $2^x+3^x=6$. What you can do is prove that for any $y>0$ there exists a unique solution of the equation $\text{"complicated LHS"}=y$.

Answer (score 1):

For MATLAB, you can use

> `x = fzero(fun,x0)` tries to find a zero of fun near `x0`.. [more in help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fzero.html)

First, define a function $f(x)$ with

```
f(x) = @(x) 1.0221044505936159^x + 1.0446975079232772^x + 
            1.0677899723724409^x + 1.091392883061106^x +
            1.1155175231229544^x + 1.140175425099138^x +
            1.1653783764512973^x + 1.1911384251964328^x + 
            1.2174678856663448^x + 1.24437934439437^x +
            1.2718856661322526^x + 1.3287357857717006^x +
            1.3581067603002603^x + 1.3881269640841731^x + 
            1.4188107479794378^x + 1.3^x - 21
```

Now solve $f(x) = 0$ using a guess $x_0 = 1$:

```
fzero(f, 1)
```

which gives the answer $$\boxed{x = 1.409102331830407}$$

The help page state the method is

> The algorithm, which was originated by T. Dekker, uses a combination of bisection, secant, and inverse quadratic interpolation methods.